# Dynamic TreeView user Control

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am working on a page with Treeview properties. This page has set of html links which looks as following:

```
1.Parent 
  1.1 child
  1.2 child
      1.2.1 grandchild ....
```

I generate this page by dynamically loading a xml file. Now I want to provide user with an option to add parent/ child links on the UI, and update the database and XML file soon user makes any changes.

I am clueless about how to proceed for this problem. Please provide me any references or hints to do this.Thank you

Comment: Without any code to look at we're clueless too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished working on this problem ! it works fine now :) I created crud methods in business layer to do this

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your binding your treeview to a XML file, like this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/7fc1c90f-7004-4ffd-829b-facd05f6135d

Then when a user adds a node you should add it to the XML and then save the XML file.

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("doc.xml")
```

Now you have the XML stored in a XmlDocument member variable, simply write a method to add nodes e.g.

```
Sub AddNode(ByVal name As String)
  Dim nameEl As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("name")
  nameEl.InnerText = name
  doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(nameEl)
End Sub
```

Then save changes later with e.g.

```
doc.Save("doc.xml")
```

Comment: @NicholeGrace, I just stumbled on this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12606/Loading-and-Saving-XML-to-and-from-a-TreeView-Cont